# Как скрывать блок раз и навсегда

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Здравствуйте, стоит задача чтобы скрывать блок раз и навсегда, допустим человек зашедший первый раз на сайт его увидел и если он нажмет на кнопку "закрыть" то чтобы это блок больше не появлялся при обновлении страницы, то есть надо заносить данные, что он скрыт в куки. Я пытался это сделать так, но не знаю вообще с чего начать правильно и чем закончить

```
$('.info__btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide(200);
 });

    if(!Cookie().get('offer')) { $('.info').hide(); }





<div class="info">
            <div class="info__btn">Закрыть</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Куки чистятся, хранилища - тоже, сохранения на сервере подвержены взлому и изменению, в шаблоны можно добавить вручную блок, расширение может само добавить блок... Нет, **навсегда** не выйдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с php

```
 <script>
            $('.info__btn').on('click', function() {
               $('html').append("<?=$_COOKIE['info__btn']='true';?>");
             });
            </script>
            <?if(!$_COOKIE['info__btn'])
            {?>
            <div class="info">
            <div class="info__btn">Закрыть</div>
             </div>
            <?}
```

Вариант с js:

```
        <div class="info" style="display:none">
        <div class="info__btn">Закрыть</div>
        </div>



    <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if(!$.cookie('info__btn'))$('.info').show();
        $('.info__btn').on('click', function() {
        $.cookie('info__btn', 'true');
        });
    })
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65957/discussion-between-liem-and-).

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Собственно сама функция которая работает с Cookie'сами
const Cookie = {
  get: function( name ) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));

    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
  },
  set: function( name, value, options ) {
    options = options || {};

    var expires = options.expires;

    if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
      expires = options.expires = d;
    }

    if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
      options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
    }

    value = encodeURIComponent(value);

    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

    for (var propName in options) {
      updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
      var propValue = options[propName];
      if (propValue !== true) {
        updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
      }
    }

    document.cookie = updatedCookie;

    return null;
  },
  delete: function( name ) {
    Cookie().set(name, '', {expires: -1});

    return null;
  }
};

// Наш обработчик всего этого безобразия (хотя лучше бы на беке делать)
$(() => {
  const $info = $('.info'),
    $infoButton  = $info.find('.info__btn');
    
  /*
  * Проверяем есть ли в куках то что нам нужно
  */
  if(Cookie.get('offer') !== 'accept') {
    /*
    * Если нет, то добавляем нашему блоку класс .show, что бы он отображался
    * И вешаем обработчик нажатия кнопки
    */
    $info.addClass('show');
    
    $infoButton.on('click', () => {
      Cookie.set('offer', 'accept');
      $info.hide();
    });
  } else {
    /*
    * Если есть, то просто удаляем наш блок
    */
    $info.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.info { display: none; } // Скрываем блок по дефолту

.info.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  <div class="info__btn">Закрыть</div>
</div>
```